# .net C# how to create an API with CXML as input and return CXML as output? Any tutorial?

Tags: c#, .net

i would need to build an API using .net framework.

I am new to the .net application where my app need to consume input from SAP system which put cxml as input and i would need to generate cxml back. Any suggestion/idea will be amazing and thanks in advance!

Comment: Assuming that you mean https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CXML, I'm pretty sure the answer is "yes". From that article _"cXML is based on XML and provides formal XML schemas"_. It's pretty easy to wrote XML-oriented code in C#. Having Schena simplifies things. There are no special CXML features, but it's just XML, and there are lots of XML features